# Finding function $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y), \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f$ continuous at $x=0$, and there exist $a$ such that $f(a)=0$, find $f(x)$.

I have read the definition of continuous function at $x=x_0$ in $E$, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$, such that for all $x_1\in E$ with $\vert x_0-x_1\vert<\delta$, then satisfied $\vert f(x_0)-f(x_1)\vert<\varepsilon$.

In my problem, $f$ continuous at $x=0$, so for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $\delta>0$, such that for all $x_1\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\vert -x_1\vert<\delta$, then satisfied $$\vert f(0)-f(x_1)\vert\leq\varepsilon.$$

I don't know to find $f(x)$. How can I get $f(x)$? Thanks..

Comment: A (nonrigorous) way to see this might be to note that the exponential function satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and then noting that the exponential function is never zero.

Comment: you are right. So, the answer is not exponential function

Comment: Hey! would you mind [accepting the answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6984/is-it-wrong-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-an-answer)? Much appreciated.

Comment: Okay. I'm forget accept your answer. Now I accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we see
$$f(x)=f(a+(x-a))=f(a)f(x-a)=0\cdot f(x-a)=0$$
Therefore, $f$ is the constant $0$ function.

Comment: thank you so much.. So we cannot find answer from the definition of continuous function?

Comment: We do not need to know that this function is continuous in order to come to the above conclusion. However, since any constant function is continuous, we do see that the resulting function is indeed continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much @RomainS